# How to alter a table to add a constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle

So, the question I have is:

> Due to various values entered by users for the status of the facility, this leads
>   to confusion. The database owner would like to limit the following values
>   “Open”, “Closed”, “Reserved”, and “Maintenance” to be used for the status of
>   facility.

My table FACILITY has the following columns:

```
FACILITYNAME
RATE
STATUS
```

I tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE FACILITY ADD CONSTRAINT FACILITY_STATUS 'Open','Closed','Reserved','Maintenance' FOR STATUS;
```

I get an error, ORA-00904:invalid identifier

I then tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE FACILITY ADD CONSTRAINT STATUS_CHECK CHECK (STATUS IN ('Open','Closed','Reserved','Maintenance'));
```

It said table altered, but when I tried updating the STATUS column, with 'abc' and 'Open', it says row updated, but nothing happened. I was expecting it to give me a constraint error for 'abc', and updating it to 'Open'.

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying. If the table originally contained abc in the status column, then your `alter table` statement should have failed. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d1bad4dca8fbd5b233da9f8678da44f9 . Further,I still don't get it when you say *" I tried updating the STATUS column, with 'abc' and 'Open'"*

Comment: @KaushikNayak The table initially didn't contain any values in the status column. I tried to update the status column after the check constraint, in hopes of seeing that it would say my constraint was violated, but it didn't. I then tried to update the row to add 'Open', and it didn't add it in.

Comment: I think there's no problem with your syntax(it should be working), by the way converting your constraint to `....CHECK (initcap(STATUS) IN ....` would be finer against case-sensitive cases.

Comment: Can you paste the output from the following query? `select search_condition,status,deferrable,deferred from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'STATUS_CHECK';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange, for me it is working as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE FACILITY (
    FACILITYNAME VARCHAR2(100),
    RATE INTEGER,
    STATUS VARCHAR2(20));
Table created.

INSERT INTO FACILITY VALUES ('f1', 1, 'Open');
1 row created.

ALTER TABLE FACILITY ADD CONSTRAINT STATUS_CHECK CHECK (STATUS IN ('Open','Closed','Reserved','Maintenance'));
Table altered.

UPDATE FACILITY SET STATUS = 'abc';

ORA-02290: check constraint (XXX.STATUS_CHECK) violated
```

Maybe verify the status of the constraint:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, STATUS, DEFERRABLE, DEFERRED 
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FACILITY';

+------------------------------------------------+
|CONSTRAINT_NAME|STATUS |DEFERRABLE    |DEFERRED |
+------------------------------------------------+
|STATUS_CHECK   |ENABLED|NOT DEFERRABLE|IMMEDIATE|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Also note, unless you give clause `VALIDATE` in your ALTER TABLE the constraint does not check existing values! By default only new and updated values are affected by the constraint.

Comment: So, for some reason, I guess my Oracle was bugging out. Had to completely reinstall it. Works fine now. Thanks for the VALIDATE tip!

Answer (score 3):

As @KaushikNayak suggested try adding check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE FACILITY  ADD CONSTRAINT check_status CHECK (FACILITY_STATUS IN ('Open','Closed','Reserved','Maintenance'));
```

Otherwise, [Column level constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html) must use another column:

> a column-level constraint
>   Column-level constraints refer to a single column in the table and do not specify a column name (except check constraints). They **refer to the column that they follow**.

I suggest you `create table FACILITY_STATUS` with column `STATUS` as Primary key and insert the values.

Then add constraint to `FACILITY` table `STATUS` column using `FACILITY_STATUS(STATUS)` as foreign key

Comment: Is there a way to add the constraint without having to drop and recreate the table?

Comment: @Vaunt I didn't suggest to recreate table

Comment: Ohhh my bad I misread that. So is the only way to add a constraint is to create a table and use that as a constraint?

Comment: @Vaunt updated my answer, Column level constraint must use another column

Comment: The Op is interested in Check constraint and I don't see any particular reason to suggest a `foreign key` instead.

Comment: @KaushikNayak you can answer a better solution

Comment: @KaushikNayak the OP wants to *limit* the possible values and *assumed* that a check constraint would be the solution. A foreign key is just another way to solve the real problem

Comment: @Hans : I understand that foreign key could be an alternative.But, all I was suggesting was that instead of troubleshooting the OP's problem at hand that's related to check  constraint, there's no need to suggest the alternative yet.

Comment: @Vaunt updated my answer with adding check constraint